# AJAX only loading in IE once

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I can not figure out why the following AJAX code will only load the information from my php page one time in IE, works in all other browsers with no problem.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;

function randomize(str)
{

if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("dispeople").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("dispeople").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","randomize.php?q=" + Math.random(),false);
xmlhttp.send();

document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c+1;
}

setInterval( "randomize()", 2000 );
</script>
```

I am fairly new to using AJAX and have researched this issue and implemented all the solutions I could find, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update, 10/21/2011

I have checked out JQuery and implemented it and am still experiencing the same issue if anyone has any suggestions here is the code I am currently using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;

$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
 });

   setInterval(function() {
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'randomize.php?ck=' + (new Date()).getTime(), 
     cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

          $('#dispeople').html(data);
     }
     });
     },2000);


</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Try using jquery/mootools instead. They nicely wrap the native browser ajax functionality into a small package, so your entire script there could be collapsed down into maybe 4 or 5 lines of code... and they also compensate for all the variations between browsers, so you're not stuck with "if (ie) ... else" monstrosities.

Comment: Thanks I am looking at using Jquery instead right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your jquery code is fine. It happens due to ie browser caching. Try sending a random value with your request and return the time() from php side to see if it is actually calling the php script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
setInterval( randomize, 2000 );
```

Also you are sending **nothing** as a string. and the 1st part of your code:

```
  if (str=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("dispeople").innerHTML="";
    return;//return, only run once....
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried the setInterval piece and wound up removing the bit of code you were referring too where I wasn't sending anything.  Still seems to be a hang up in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a reason you're not using it already, but I highly recommend checking out [jQuery](http://jquery.com). That library automatically smoothes out all of these browser incompatibility issues, so you can just worry about *your* functionality.

Comment: Thanks, as suggested I have looked at JQuery, I am still running into the same issue using the following code:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
       setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: 'randomize.php',
        success: function(data) {
             $('#dispeople').html(data);
        }
     });
      },2000);
 
</script>